# Datae Tables Dynamically show/hide columns is not working in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, datatables

I am trying to implement dynamically show hide columns in rails using dataTable plugin.

The show Hide button is visible but when I uncheck a column it is not disappearing from the table. The column should appear only when I click on check mark true, if I uncheck it it should be not in the columns list.

Please help me how to fix this!.

_merchent.html.erb             # partail file

```
<div id="merchant_list" class="panel-body">
    <div  class="table-success">
      <table id = "table_id" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Merchant</th>
          <th>Bank Name</th>
          <th>Payment Gateway</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Discount</th>
          <th>Additional Charges</th>
          <th>Added On</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="details">
        <% @all_settlement_details.each do |sd| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= sd.merchantname %></td>
              <td><%= sd.bank_name  %></td>
              <td><%= sd.payment_gateway %></td>
              <td><%= get_status(sd.status) %></td>
              <td><%= sd.amount %></td>
              <td><%= sd.discount %></td>
              <td><%= sd.additional_charges%></td>
              <td><%= get_added_on_date sd.addedon %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div id="align">
        <a href="" class="load-more" data-clicks="1">Load more...</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

merchant.js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#table_id').DataTable({
   "dom": 'C&gt;"clear"&lt;lfrtip',
   paging: false,
   searching: false
});
```

Please see the corresponding image as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "scrollY": "200px",
        "paging": false
    } );

    $('a.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the column API object
        var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );

        // Toggle the visibility
        column.visible( ! column.visible() );
    } );
} );
```

We need to see your code that is attached to the checkboxes to know further what you problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

After few hours, I finally figured out the solution.!
Everything is fine but the datatable libraries that I included were out dated. So I changed those  two  libraries. Now it is working.

```
http://cdn.datatables.net/colvis/1.1.1/css/dataTables.colVis.css

http://cdn.datatables.net/colvis/1.1.1/js/dataTables.colVis.min.js
```